# Load files from vendors directory in SlimPHP

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I started playing with SlimPHP so I want to include Twitter Bootstrap files which are located inside /vendor/twitter/bootstrap dist directory.

When I use absolute URL I get not found.

So what are the best approaches to include files from each vendor directory like Bootstrap?

Website structure:

website

```
---app

---public

---vendors
   ---twitter
          ---bootstrap
                 ---dist
                        ---css
                        ---js
                        ---fonts
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Slim; is vendor outside of your document root?

Comment: Yes @Scott Please see the directory structure above.

Comment: In order for JS, CSS, or fonts to be usable from a web context, they must be included in `public/`

Answer (score 0):

You can configure [twig asset](https://github.com/careys7/slim-twig-asset)

and use it like this

```
<link href="{{ asset('vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Try and use something like [bower](http://bower.io/) to manage front-end dependencies, the bootstrap codebase should not be used from composer, this is bad and I am not sure why anyone would have implemented this.